# How do berry mutations work?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

So I planted some berries at that farm just before the bridge with Snorlax on it, in the hope of expanding my supply. I watered them, came back the next day and each tree had sprouted nicely. However, some of them had an oddly-coloured berry, which (upon picking) I found out was a berry of an entirely different type altogether.

Some scientist then came up to me, and told me she was 'researching berry mutations' and that I should tell her what mutations I find.

My mutation was a *Qualot Berry*, which (according to the scientist) was made from *Oran* and *Pecha Berries*. But how did this happen?

Is it something to do with the way the bushes are planted next to each other, or in a line? Or Is it completely random?

Further to this, What other Berry Mutations can I find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I feel silly now, I just found a nice [guide](http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/448581-the-berry-farm) that sums it up nicely:

> ...In essence, what this means is that when certain Berries are planted next to each other, there is a chance for 1 or more of those berries to mutate into a entirely different berry

**Known Mutations**:

1. Oran + Peacha = Qualot
2. Iapapa + Mago = Pomeg
3. Aspear + Leppa = Hondew
4. Chesto + Persim = Kelpsy
5. Kelpsy + Wacan = Apicot
6. Qualot + Tanga = Ganlon
7. Aguav + Figy = Grepa
8. Liechi + Ganlon = Kee
9. Hondew + Yache = Liechi
10. Salac + Petaya = Maranga
11. Pomeg + Kasib = Petaya
12. Grepa + Roseli = Salac
13. Sitrus + Lum = Tamato

**Sources**:

- [Pokemon X and Y Forums](http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/448581-the-berry-farm)
- [Serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/xy/berryfields.shtml)
- Personal Experience (No link for this, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Lum + sitrus = tamato

I found this one this morning.